# How to read custom text from external html with fopen in PHP

Tags: php, html, fopen

I wanna read an specified word from an external website, I have an website about mobile phones and I wanna implement price for all models from database, so with help of `fopen()`
I will open an etxternal website like `website.com/nokia5500.html` so from website source to get the price (external website is an shopping website)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/zh/book.curl.php), [file_get_content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [file_get_content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to request to an external website as Xingjia mentioned.
Then, use [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) or [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse the HTML document and get the specific text you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use YQL: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ the Yahoo! Query Language